# Shouldn't UISwitch work the opposite way?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm confused over why my code works in the opposite way than I originally thought it would. Below is how my code currently functions:

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func SwitchTap(sender: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.on {                           //prints on if turning on
        mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
        print ("switch is on")
    }
    else {
        mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        print("switch is off")              //prints off if turning off
    }
```

This is how I think it should work:

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func SwitchTap(sender: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.on {
        mySwitch.setOn(**false**, animated: true) // should be false instead of true like in the previous example
        print ("switch is on")
    }
    else {
        mySwitch.setOn(**true**, animated: true) //should be true instead of false like in the previous example
        print("switch is off")
    }
```

I don't understand why the first version works but the second one doesn't. [SetOn](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn:animated:) should turn the switch off when passed false as the first argument. Instead it is turning it off when passed true and simply doesn't change states.

Comment: Is your `SwitchTap` function tied to a tap gesture you added to the `UISwitch` or is it tied to the "ValueChanged" control event? If the latter, you really should rename the function to be less confusing.

Comment: Off-topic but definitely interesting to read: [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that `UISwitch` toggles its value on end-user's tap.

Your `SwitchTap` gets invoked together with the switch togging its value internally. Your first code leaves the state the same, so when the switch toggles it, the end result is a toggle. Your second code, however, inverts the state, so when `UISwitch' toggles it, the switch stays in its original state, because two toggles cancel each other.

Removing all calls to `setOn` will fix your code.

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you very much

Comment: No, `SwitchTap` is invoked after the switch has toggled its state. Suppose the switch is off and the user taps it. The switch sets itself to on and calls `SwitchTap`. Then `SwitchTap` (in Jacob's second version) sets the state back to off (false). So tapping the switch has no effect (“simply doesn't change states”).

Comment: @robmayoff You are right, the order of who does the inversion first is irrelevant, the code or the switch. I edited the answer to remove the mention that OP's code acts before the switch.